# How to connect the lines in the simplest way?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I connect the lines of the simplest form in the following code. Perhaps with chain or other option, so that the code is short.

```
\usetikzlibrary{chains,calc}
\newcommand{\xx}{10}
\newcommand{\yy}{9}
\newcounter{x}    %novo contador
\setcounter{x}{1} %valor inicial do contador
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,start chain=dot placed {at=(\tikzchaincount*30:1.5)}]
    %grade
    \draw[very thin,color=lightgray,dashed] (0,0) grid (\xx+1,\yy+1);
    %eixos
    \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (\xx+1,0) node[below] {$n^\circ$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,\yy+1) node[right] {altura $(m)$};
    %cotas
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\xx}
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt)
            node[below]     {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\yy}
    \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt)
        node[left] {$\y 0$};
    \node[below left] at (0,0) {$0$};
    %grafico
    \foreach \y in {1,3,2,4,5,1,3,6,8,9}{
        \fill[blue] (\thex,\y) circle (2pt);
        \coordinate (p\thex) at (\thex,\y);
        \draw (p\thex) -- (p\thex); %CONECT LINES HERE
        \pgfmathsetcounter{x}{\thex+1} %soma 1 no contador
        \setcounter{x}{\thex} %redefine o contador
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I need this.
[image]

I solve with

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\xx}{10}
\newcommand{\yy}{9}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    %grade
    \draw[very thin,color=lightgray,dashed] (0,0) grid (\xx+1,\yy+1);
    %eixos
    \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (\xx+1,0) node[below] {$n^\circ$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,\yy+1) node[right] {altura $(m)$};
    %cotas
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\xx}
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt)
            node[below]     {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\yy}
    \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt)
        node[left] {$\y 0$};
    \node[below left] at (0,0) {$0$};
    %grafico
    \coordinate (p1) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (p2) at (2,3);
    \coordinate (p3) at (3,2);
    \coordinate (p4) at (4,4);
    \coordinate (p5) at (5,5);
    \coordinate (p6) at (6,1);
    \coordinate (p7) at (7,3);
    \coordinate (p8) at (8,6);
    \coordinate (p9) at (9,8);
    \coordinate (p10) at (10,9);

    \draw plot[mark=*,mark options={blue}] coordinates{
        (p1)(p2)(p3)
        (p4)(p5)(p6)
        (p7)(p8)(p9)
        (p10)
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Why do you want to plot your data this way? It would be a lot easier to just use `pgfplots`, or at least the `plot` functionality that comes with TikZ. I believe you might get better answers if you explained the motivation behind your approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a `pgfplots` solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ xlabel=$n^{\circ}$, ylabel=Altura,
              grid=major, axis lines = left, 
              xmin = 0, ymin= 0, xmax=11,ymax=100, 
              major grid style={dashed},
              xtick={0,1,...,10},ytick={0,10,...,90}] 
\addplot[color=blue,mark=*] 
coordinates {
    (1,10) 
    (2,30) 
    (3,20) 
    (4,40) 
    (5,50) 
    (6,10) 
    (7,30) 
    (8,60) 
    (9,80) 
    (10,90)
};
\end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]